# set variable before res.render in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to set userGameList to User.games, but res.render does not await for the variable, the first log is what I expect but the second is an empty string. I've tried with async and await.

```
app.get('/games', async (req, res) => {

  var userGameList = "";

  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    User.findById(req.user.id, async function(err, foundUser) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
      } else {
        if (foundUser) {
          userGameList = await foundUser.games;
          console.log(userGameList); // log with the right value
        }
      }
    })
  };

  console.log(userGameList); // log empty string

  res.render('pages/games-list', {
    req: req,
    parentPage: "/",
    pageTitle: "Games",
    myUserGames: userGameList
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You return the response once `userGameList` is available in the async method.

This is nature of async function (User.findById) which unless awaited will release the thread for next code block execution. And once response is received async function executes the callback.

```
app.get('/games', async (req, res) => {

  var userGameList = "";

  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    User.findById(req.user.id, async function(err, foundUser) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
      } else {
        if (foundUser) {
          userGameList = await foundUser.games;
          console.log(userGameList); // log with the right value

            res.render('pages/games-list', {
              req: req,
              parentPage: "/",
              pageTitle: "Games",
              myUserGames: userGameList
            });
        }
      }
    })
  };
```

Comment: I tried but with this code the app hangs and does not load the page, also, I need to load the page even if not authenticated.

Comment: I think the app hangs because of some error that occurs inside the else part because you are not handling all the conditions there. Also, isnt the page not loading when its not authenticated?

Comment: That can happen, but you are getting value here `console.log(userGameList);  // log with the right value`, then it should work

Comment: It hangs 100% of the times if I'm not logged

Comment: that will happen and that's one use case. But the primary concern is, are you seeing page with userGameList back?

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath Yes it does work indeed, only problem is the hanging. I would add another "else" to "if authenticated()" with another res.render but I'd like a more elegant solution

Comment: Ok, yup, you need to return response on else